# how to log user getting access to path denied on windows server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, windows-server-2012-r2, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package that fails on a step that copies a file from server 1 to another server 2. I get

> access to path \server2\f$\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.mdb denied

I have give "everyone" all access on the dir3 subdirectory and still it does not work.

I'd like to see what user the system is trying to use to copy the file and I have looked at the Security error logs but can not find the attempted log in.

How can get the windows to log the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the SSIS package from SQL Server, then you have to give permission to the SQL Database Engine Service account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)